# How can I find the gparted package in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, gparted, repository, apt

I recently upgraded my chromebook c710-2856's hard drive to a 250GB drive and flashed coreboot on it. I then proceeded to install debian wheezy with LXDE.

I want to install gparted, and when I do:

```
# apt-get install gparted
```

I get:
E: Unable to locate package gparted

I am able to find other packages it seems, just not gparted.

Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7 _Wheezy_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20140723-17:29]/ wheezy main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7 _Wheezy_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20140723-17:29]/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free contrib
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy contrib non-free main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main non-free contrib
```

I installed debian from a live USB.

How can I fix my repositories?

By the way, I have the wheezy-backports repo because it contains a package for the specific trackpad drivers I need for my chromebook.

**EDIT: I managed to install gparted manually through dpkg -i gparted_(version name).deb, but I still would like to figure this out as I cannot find packages such as xbacklight.**

Comment: Just to be sure, you did do: `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install gparted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debian: How to find which repository a package is located in?](https://superuser.com/questions/811206/debian-how-to-find-which-repository-a-package-is-located-in)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put the # (comment out) in front of the cdrom source at the top so it will always pull from the repos on debian.org and never search for the packages on the cdrom.